# Ajax error - errorThrown in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ssl

I am writing an asp.net MVC application that will compliment another application that I have written. In my old application, I send errors from the controller to the client like so:

`return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Whatever went wrong.")`

Then, on my client side the ajax error looks a little like this:

`error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                redAlert(errorThrown);
            }`

This all works perfectly. Whatever message I put in on the controller side will pop up on the client side.

Now, I have tried to do the same thing with this new application. However, `errorThrown` has nothing in it every time.

I have no idea where to start looking so any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

After talking through some stuff with Shyju, it seems that `HttpStatusCodeResult` is not sending the message back in the header in the new application. Still trying to work this out.

**Edit 2**

After some testing, I have found that the Custom Error message doesn't get sent through using SSL. Why would this be an issue and how can I solve this? I need to use SSL as the application requires Work Account Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

When your server code returns a 400 bad request response **from your web api controller**, the message text you are sending will be in the response from the server as

```
{"Message":"Whatever went wrong."}
```

Now the `$.ajax` will use this response and create a js object from that and set it to the `responseJSON` property of the `jqXHR` object. So you may simply access that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourApiEndpoint' 
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
        alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.Message);
    }
});
```

When you return `HttpStatusCodeResult` **from an MVC controller action method**, IIS will return the markup for the 400 page. So the response is basically the HTML markup. The response headers  will have the status code and the message and the `$.ajax` method will set the status message you send from server to the `statusText` property of the xhr object.

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     if (jqXHR.statusText) {
         alert(jqXHR.statusText);
     }
});
```

Comment: My jqXHR does not seem to have a responseJSON. And it errorThrown works on the other application so I have to be doing something write in the old app. I also tried change error to fail and it didn't trigger at all.

Comment: What is the response code from the server call ? If it is 400, The `fail` handler to should be fired. What version of jQuery are you using ? I tested with jQuery 3.2.1 and it worked when the server returns 400 with the message.

Comment: I was under the impression it was from a web api controller. If you are returning that from an MVC controller, you need to use the `statusText` property. See the updated answer.

Comment: I am using 3.2.1 as well. The `statusText` property is just returning "error". I just don't understand how it is working in one application and not in another.

Comment: What is the status header for the response ? is it 400 ?

Comment: That is the one that I am testing with at the moment, however, the same thing happens with 500. But in the old application, it works with 400's and 500's.

Comment: Do you have custom error pages setup in the app. Check what is the response status coming back. It should be 400

Comment: No custom error pages. When I have a look at `jgXHR.status' it says 400.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158649/discussion-between-shyju-and-johzant).

Comment: After doing some testing, it seems to be because I am using SSL. I need to be testing in SSL as it uses Work Account Authentication. So, I guess the real question would be, how can I send the Custom Error Message through to the client while still having SSL on? Added this as an edit.